# How can I embed my callback function inside the function that triggered it?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource) {

    LeanTween.value(gameObject, myCallback, 0, 1, 1f);
}

void myCallback( float val, float ratio ){

     myAudioSource.volume = val;
}
```

How can I include "`myAudioSource.volume = val;`" directly inside the LeanTween.value function, without needing to declare a separate callback function?

The reason I want it embedded is that I want to pass "myAudioSource" as a parameter in it. That way, I don't need to write a callback function for every audiosource.

Basically, I want to do something like that:

```
    void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource) {

        LeanTween.value(gameObject, () => { 
             myAudioSource.volume = val; } , 0, 1, 1f);
    }
```

But I'm not sure what syntax I should use.

Comment: The concept you're looking for is called [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).

Comment: For larger lambdas, having a separate function can be nicer visually and more easily tested directly.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The reason I want it embedded is that I want to assign an external variable "myAudioSource" to it. That way, I don't need to create a function everytime I want to use a different audiosource variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, just use a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)

```cs
void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource) {
    LeanTween.value(gameObject,
      (val, ratio) => {
        myAudioSource.volume = val;
      },
      0, 1, 1f
    );
}
```

But as you can see, it's quite hard to read as it is quite nested, also it will only get harder to read if/ when the callback gets more complicated, so it's a mixed bag.

Comment: The wrapping braces and semicolon aren't required for this very simple case, and then becomes easier to read

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few ways to do this.

You can use a lambda expression as you've already seen and heard:

```
void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource) 
{
    LeanTween.value(gameObject, (val, ratio) => myAudioSource.volume = val, 0, 1, 1f);
}
```

That's a pretty simple lambda and even with the brackets and semicolon removed it's already starting to get ugly and difficult to read. That may not be an issue in this case but there are other ways in case it is in other scenarios. For example...

Use an `Action<float, float>`*:

```
void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource)
{    
    var actionCallback = (val, ratio) => 
    { 
        // lots of code here... 
    };
    LeanTween.value(gameObject, actionCallback, 0, 1, 1f);
}
```

Use a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions):

```
void ChangeVolume(AudioSource myAudioSource)
{
    LeanTween.value(gameObject, localFunc, 0, 1, 1f);
    
    void localFunc(float val, float ratio)
    {
        // lots of code here...
    }
}
```

**If you had a callback that returned some value use `Func<T[, ...], R>`*